# Trying to run a hello.js script with node on linux

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I have a simple JS script, just a hello world program. I want to run it in the terminal using nodejs.  But when I use the node command, instead of printing my console log it tells me:

$node helloworld.js

The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install

I have updated my version of node and don't understand what else I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create symbolic link. Run following command and then you can use **node helloworld.js**

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`